# Generic class with two class hierarchies

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns

I have the following Java generics question

I have the following generic class thay may be sketched as:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    AnotherClass<T> another;
    OtherClass<T> other;
    ...
}
```

where `...` represents code that is not relevant to the case.

For the class `MyClass<T>` is not as important which exact type `T` is (as of now) but for both:

- `AnotherClass<T>`
- `OtherClass<T>`

is **absolutely crucial** what the generic type is and decisions will be made at runtime in base of that.

Based on that, the type `T` is not completely arbitrary, it may be either an instance of a hierarchy of classes `T_1` or a hierarchy of classes `T_2`.

As is defined the class, the type `T` is equivalent to `Object` but I know that is equivalent to either `T_1` or `T_2`

There is not businnes relation between entities `T_1` and `T_2` therefore I'm not doing:

```
public interface BaseT { ... }
public class T_1 implements BaseT { ... }
public class T_2 implements BaseT { ... }

public class MyClass<T extends BaseT>
```

**Clarification about why using a generic if they are unrelated:**

I'm defining (trying to) a generic class for both because even they are unrelated  explictly, there is a implicit relation because both `T_1` and  `T_2` can and will appear associated to the entity represented in `MyClass`

`T` will be the same for `MyClass`, `AnotherClass` and `OtherClass` so that in a instance there will only be either `T_1` or `T_2` but never both at the same time.

> My question is, which alternatives do I have here other than design an
>   interface for `MyClass` and implement it for both `T_1` and `T_2`?.
>
> Can I achieve something like `MyClass<T extends T_1 or T_2>`?

Kind regards

Comment: why would you use a generic T for both classes if the actual types are not related?

Comment: What's wrong with defining it as `MyClass<T, U>` or even `MyClass<T, U, V>`? This will allow you to set the bounds of every type separately.

Comment: I didn't investigate further but you could check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538133/can-i-use-java-annotations-to-define-compile-time-checks

Comment: @TimCastelijns fair question, updated OP

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen The entity represented in `MyClass` is a container for one and only one of them, not both at the same time, therefore `MyClass<T, U>` is not a proper model as far as I can tell

Comment: Oh, OK. So basically you're after something like `MyClass<T extends T1 or T2>`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen exactly, this is the pseudocode that may represent it. Thanks for that, added to the OP

Comment: That's called "union types", and I don't think Java has them (except in `catch` blocks for exceptions). You'd need to emulate it with some wrapper.

Comment: @Thilo thanks for pointing it out, and giving the "union types" reference. I found the following article (https://blog.jooq.org/2016/02/16/an-ingenious-workaround-to-emulate-sum-types-in-java/) that exactly states that some work-around is needed in Java. Would you please post an answer so future visitors may read that? Thanks

Comment: According me there is a design flaw here and you should not make runtime decisions based on the generic type specialization. Generics, templates and all type-inference languages mechanisms should not replace polymorphism

Comment: If T_1 and T_2 are that disjunct that a common interface has no value, it might be that one should make wrapper classes around T_1 and T_2 that expose common functionality stored at the moment in MyClass, AnotherClass, OtherClass. Then have a common interface. I am afraid that currently there would be instanceofs in the classes.

Comment: @JoopEggen The current implementation has a design that is far from simple (that I'm using as a proxy of design goodness) and it has a lot of `instanceof` and `getClass().equals(expectedClass)` clauses. Can you please sketch such a wrapper in an answer? Thanks

Comment: @JorgeLavín unfortunately I have no time for such an open speculative thing. At the end it might be best to duplicate the MyClass (without generics), as that might be better than adding hoops for the classes to jump through. And _than_ look whether something can be refactored. Advantage: you are starting from a working situation, with all design decisions resolved optimally.

Comment: you can always answer your own question btw with the resolution that you found...

Comment: Too theorical for me, I need a concrete example of why we would need that, or a complete pattern description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, this is not exactly what your're looking for, but you might give it a try:

Create an `abstract` generic class that implements everything:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T>
{
  AnotherClass<T> another;
  OtherClass<T> other;

  // Add any code needed

}
```

Then create 2 generic classes for both base classes.
These classes may be empty if all code can be implemented in the abstract one:

```
public class MyT1Class<T extends T_1> extends MyClass<T>
{
}

public class MyT2Class<T extends T_2> extends MyClass<T>
{
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing this, with two `interfaces`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a very good answer but I couldn't leave it as a comment to the question.
You can check the type at runtime by trying the following:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
  // This factory-method creates an instance of the class if the correct type is passed
  // It throws a RuntimeException if not.
  public static <T> MyClass<T> getInstance(Class<T> type)
  {
    if (T_1.class.isAssignableFrom(type) || T_2.class.isAssignableFrom(type))
      return (new MyClass<T>());
    else
      throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create instance of MyClass<" + type.getName() + ">");
  }

  ...

}
```

Then

```
class T_3 extends T_2
{
}

....

MyClass<T_3> test_1;
test_1 = MyClass.getInstance(T_3.class); // This will succeed

MyClass<String> test_2;
test_2 = MyClass.getInstance(String.class); // Fails
```

Comment: Thanks @RobertKock. Your code uses `isAssignableFrom` and a `if  - then` clause which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @JorgeLavín I already guessed you wanted a design-time solution.