# Imported javax.annotation not found in jar dependencies

Tags: java, spring

In the library spring-core in the file NonNull.java (spring core lang) is the following:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.meta.TypeQualifierNickname;
```

But when I use Spring boot app, I cannot see any library inside my fat JAR which defines such  annotations. And I do not think that they are part of Java 17. Still my application which uses @NonNull annotation works. How it is possible? Am I missing something?
EDITED:
It seems to me, that it is possible to create annotation A in package A referencing to another annotation B in package B and does not have runtime dependency on library which defines B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These annotations are processed at compile time, you don't need any code at runtime for them. You can check their retention policy.

[More details in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538133/can-i-use-java-annotations-to-define-compile-time-checks).

[JavaDoc for annotation retention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html)